# Test the egret project use the intern-unit test error occurred

Tags: module, external, intern

I use the Egret to develop, import the external modules(ex : puremvc).
Run unit test through use intern.

When I run npm test, occurred error. Following the picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7dZ.png)

I found the project processing, didn't import the external modules. So I place the 'import' and 'require' at the test file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62NXj.png)

run and occurred error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xURIw.png)

All the external modules has three types:
EX:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuECM.png)

I don't want to revise the external modules, because they can working well on the Egret.

How can I resolve the problem?

There are three another questions:

1. Used inheritance in the object, and inherited object is the external module. How do I set and adjustment in the test?
2. How to test the static object?
3. If the module didn't add 'export', whether has other method to import module?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample project: https://github.com/theintern/intern/files/1538260/traintest.zip

Comment: The sample project doesn't actually build when running `npm install` followed by `npm run build`. Are there additional build steps?